# Workaround needed for EF Core performing GroupBy operations in memory instead of in SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working in Entity Framework Core 1.1.0 (and upgrading is not an option at this point, due to breaking changes in later versions). My query is of the following form:

```
var q = db.MyTable
            .GroupBy(t => new { t.Field1 })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.Field1,
                MaxField2 = g.Max(x => x.Field2)
            })
            .ToList();
```

In test code this works well and returns the expected data. But when deployed to a real environment, with real data, it times out. Why? Well, I put a sniffer on the SQL server, and here's the actual SQL:

```
SELECT [t].[Field1], [t].[Field2], [t].[Field3], [t].[Field4], [t].[Field5]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[Field1]
```

Oh. Well that would explain it. EF is only compiling the query up to the `.GroupBy()` into SQL, thus attempting to load the *entire* contents of the table (some 17 million records at this time of writing) into memory, and the rest of the grouping and ordering is supposed to be done in memory.

Any suggestions how to rework this query so that the heavy lifting is done in SQL?

Comment: why don't you make your query a bit more readable to avoid exceptions? use variables `Expression<Func<>>` and work with them. I don't think anyone wants to rebuild your DB-structure from scratch, work with an old version of EF Core and debug this completely for you.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger see my update.

Comment: @ShaulBehr Have you tested this "reduced" query? Does it shows the same "problem"?

Comment: @xanatos, yes, I have tested the reduced query. Same behavior.

Comment: If you need such queries, EF Core is the biggest mistake you've made :( No workarounds, whatever you try it either generates exception or executes in memory. And no arbitrary SQL query supported.

Comment: @IvanStoev not totally accurate. I found a workaround; see my answer.

Comment: Good for you! Until you need  another aggregate like `Sum` :)

Comment: @IvanStoev (shuffles feet awkwardly) um... well... 8-\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @xanatos points out, this is is not supported in EF Core 1.1.0 (and not even 2.0.0). There is, however, a workaround, using literal SQL:

```
var q = db.MyTable
        .FromSql("select t.* from " +
                 "  (select distinct Field1 from MyTable) t0 " +
                 "cross apply " +
                 "  (select top 1 t.* from MyTable t " +
                 "  where t.Field1 = t0.Field1 " +
                 "  order by t.Field2 desc) t")                     
        .Select(t => new
        {
            t.Field1,
            MaxField2 = t.Field2
        })
        .ToList();
```

Not the solution I'd hoped for, but it works a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Not supported in EF Core 1.1.0: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2341

> LINQ's GroupBy() operators can sometimes be translated to SQL's GROUP BY clauses, in particular when aggregate functions are applied in the projection.

Sadly it won't be supported even in EF Core 2.0.0.

Comment: For a more complete list of what is already there or not. Take a look at this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in this [blog entry](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap#ef-core-20), `GROUP BY` will be supported in 2.1, which isn't released yet, but [expected for Q1-Q2 2018](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) <s>Q4 2017</s>.

Comment: It seems they have postponed 2.1 release to Q1-Q2 2018 :(