# Group by x into sum Performance (VB.Net --> C#) .net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently redoing some LOB Apps with a lot of query work in it.

The original was a lightswitch vb.net project but since i wanted to learn C# and base the new versions on current technologies it is now a ASP.Net Core 2.0 project.

Anyways, I'm trying to migrate this query (VB.Net) to C#:

```
      Return From x In _DB
      Where x.Amount<> 0
      Group By x.str1, x.str2 Into Sum(x.Amount)
      Where Sum < 0
      Select New Object With {...}
```

I translated this into something like this:

```
     from x in _DB
     where x.Amount!= 0
     group x by new { x.str1, x.str2} into GROUP
     where GROUP.Sum(s => s.Amount) < 0
     select new Model()
     {

        ...

     }
```

The Output is correct and I use it in smaller queries but in table with ~ 1.000.000 rows the difference in performance is massive. VB: 3 seconds, C#: 45 Seconds.

Is there a better translation for "group into sum" in C# or might the performance issue lie elsewhere?

Edit:

So i tried to profile both versions with Linqpad and to my surprise they both performed more or less equally and they both converted to identical SQL:

```
 DECLARE @p0 Decimal(21,20) = 0
 DECLARE @p1 Decimal(21,20) = 0

 SELECT [t1].[Artikelnr_] AS [Artikelnummer], [t1].[Lagerortcode], [t1].
 [value2] AS [Bestand]
 FROM (
 SELECT SUM([t0].[Menge]) AS [value], SUM([t0].[Menge]) AS [value2], [t0].
 [Artikelnr_], [t0].[Lagerortcode]
 FROM [DB$Artikelposten] AS [t0]
 WHERE [t0].[Menge] <> @p0
 GROUP BY [t0].[Artikelnr_], [t0].[Lagerortcode]
 ) AS [t1]
 WHERE [t1].[value] < @p1
```

That's weird. Maybe it is more a problem with the .net CORE 2.0 Interpreter? For obvious reasons i cant test that with vb.net (;

Comment: Have you used a profiler to see what queries are actually generated?  That is a massive difference... looks like the c# version is bringing all the data back and doing the grouping in memory.

Comment: Have you tried the lambda version (I tend to prefer this personally... )`_DB.Where(x=>x.Amount != 0).GroupBy(x=>new{x.str1, x.str2).Where(g=>g.Sum(s=>s.Amount) < 0).Select(x=> new Model(){...})`

Comment: @GPW Missing a closing squiggly bracket in your `GroupBy`.

Comment: @smnnekho It looks like your two grouping properties are strings, as they're named `x.strN`, so you could concat them and use that as the grouping key instead of creating an anonymous object. IE: `group x by x.str1 + x.str2 into GROUP`

Comment: What exactly is `_DB`? Just to make sure your using the IQueryable to perform this task, can you create a variable like this: `IQueryable<MyDbTable> dbQueryable = _DB;` and then use the `dbQueryable` in your linq query?

Comment: @IPValverde is just tried to simplify the code. _DB is actually an EnitityFramework DBcontext respectively a specific DbSet / table of it.

Comment: @GPW i tried the lambda version - unfortunatly it doesn't make a noticable difference.

Comment: @GPW i didn't try profiling yet - not sure how to do it with just VS acutally. i remembered i used something called linqpad in the past - i might check both version with that. you are probably right though regarding what is executed where. i'm @ home now and trying it via a remote VPN connection and the response time for the vb.net version is the same. the c# version is unusuable and even runs into a timeout...

Comment: @GPW i tried to profile both versions with linqpad and edited my original post with the results.

Comment: You should compare c# 4.x vs c# core 2.0. The vb.net part of this question may cloud what is really going on.

Comment: @djv you are right - is just realized that. it could also be related to Entity Framework .Net Core

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction.

Unfortunatly this has someting to with EF Core wherey up until 2.0 GroupBy is NOT beeing translated to SQL...

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184456/workaround-needed-for-ef-core-performing-groupby-operations-in-memory-instead-of) or [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2341)

it will be available in 2.1 which is not yet released.

Comment: Yes, I don't think EF Core is really up to production just yet. Maybe after 2.1 comes out...